# Let $f(x)=1/x$ on $[1, 3]$. Find $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$ when $P=\{1, 2, 3\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

My answer agrees with the solution manual, but shouldn't $L(f,P)≤U(f,P)$?  Did I do something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Wait, I think I figured this out... I picked the largest x in my interval, but I need the value of x so that 1 OVER x is the largest?  Yes??

Comment: Yes, you did everything totally backwards. The sup of $1/t$ on $[1,2]$ is $1$ and the inf is $1/2$, not the other way around.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  :)    The solution manual is wrong too then!  And it wouldn't be the first time either.  LOL